getting package org.apache.log4j does not exist ,how do I Resolve It..?
working on upgrading the log4j but getting package org.apache.log4j does not exist, how do I Resolve It..?
Used the latest version of log4j but getting level, fileappeder classes not available error
how can I resolve and fix it can you suggest that can please help on this?

Show what you have in your pom, and the actual error messages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Log4j follows semantic versioning, so version 1.x and 2.x are not binary compatible. Can you show us your code that relies on Log4j 1.x?
